# Good free dialect quizzes?

Tags: discussion, american-english

I like the [NY Times dialect quiz from 2014](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/upshot/dialect-quiz-map.html) and I'm thinking it would be fun to do as a group at work.

But the NY Times one isn't free; are there any good free ones out there?

Comment: Excellent question! Can you give more details about what you are looking for? Do you want a web page or app that asks you, an individual, a number of questions about which word you use for a given concept and then guesses where in the US or UK you were raised (identifies your local English dialect)? How do you want a group to use it... just to compare among yourselves? Do you care about pronunciation? Any additional tings you care about you should add to your question.

Comment: Trashy "popular  quizzes" on local dialectal usages are the stuff of life for cheap local (free) newspapers, but mostly they're not worth the paper they're printed on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [American accent quiz from Babbel](https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/american-accent-quiz) - short, some pronunciation, no map.
- [American accent quiz from Brainfail](https://brainfall.com/quizzes/american-dialect-quiz/) - similar to Babbel's but with morketing ads and an email signup
- [American accent quiz from Buzzfeed](https://www.buzzfeed.com/andrewziegler/dialect-quiz) - similar to Babbel's but 40 questions (longer but more accurate)
- [British accent quiz from Buzzfeed](https://www.buzzfeed.com/lukelewis/the-great-english-dialect-quiz) - similar to the American Buzzfeed quiz but with British choices
- [Cambridge Survey of World Englishes](http://www.tekstlab.uio.no/cambridge_survey/user/register) - more than US, register with email/password
- [Lexicon Valley/Gretchen McCulloch collection of of quizzes](https://slate.com/human-interest/2014/07/7-best-dialect-quizzes-is-your-accent-american-british-canadian-australian.html)

  - [Southerner or a Yankee?](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/yankeetest.html)
  - [British English](http://www.squidoo.com/british-slang-quiz)
  - [Scottish English](http://www.scotland.org/quizzes/scots-language-quiz/)
  - [Northern Irish English](http://www.inyourpocket.com/northern-ireland/belfast/How-till-spake-Norn-Iron-A-guide-to-local-phrases_70619f)
  - [Canadian English](http://geekmom.com/2013/12/55-canadianisms/)
  - [Montreal English](http://www.montrealgazette.com/news/accents/quiz/index.html)
  - [Australian English](http://alldownunder.com/australian-quiz/aussie-slang-2.htm)
  - [New Zealand English](http://gonewzealand.about.com/od/About-New-Zealand/fl/New-Zealand-Language-Accent-and-Pronunciation.htm)
- [NYTimes American Dialect Quiz](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/upshot/dialect-quiz-map.html)
- [NYTimes British-Irish Dialect Quiz](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/02/15/upshot/british-irish-dialect-quiz.html)

Here are the actual results and maps that the American quizzes are based on: [Harvard (or UVM) Dialect Survey](http://dialect.redlog.net/). The original survey occurred and was published around 2003.

[A similar question was asked on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/quiz/comments/14rmtbm/good_free_dialect_quizzes/) but with no answers.

[Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/2372/)

Comment: It's fun fun fun til the Internet link rots awa-ay: Slate subset (Lexicon Valley) takes the link for Scottish English to "404: We dinnae ken where the page has gone. Try searching for your query,"  says scotland.org (slashnothingelse). Beaucoup de link rot and misinformed titles: Canadian English is a list from a flyover, Montréal just the MTL Gazette homepage; gonewzealand.about is gone, unfortunate to syllabification at first glance, and I wish I knew a more common way to say that there.  If only there were more pulp dialect quizzes, I could for once describe the weather, but I have no word.

Comment: @Mitch haha ya got me with that reddit question, cross-posting :D